# ERROR: The supervisor is stopping, no additional scopes can be created

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

This is the error details

```
System.OperationCanceledException: The supervisor is stopping, no additional 
scopes can be created
at MassTransit.Util.TaskSupervisor.CreateScope(String tag)
at MassTransit.Util.TaskScope.MassTransit.Util.ITaskSupervisor.CreateScope(String tag)
at MassTransit.Util.TaskSupervisorExtensions.CreateScope(ITaskSupervisor supervisor, String tag, Func`1 afterStopped)
at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Integration.RabbitMqModelCache.ModelScope..ctor(ITaskScope supervisor)
at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Integration.RabbitMqModelCache.Send(IPipe`1 connectionPipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.RabbitMqSendTransport.<MassTransit-Transports-ISendTransport-Send>d__6`1.MoveNext()
--- The last part of the stack trace in the previous location that caused the exception ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Pipeline.RabbitMqBasicConsumer.<RabbitMQ-Client-IBasicConsumer-HandleBasicDeliver>d__19.MoveNext()
```

This error will appear on time,how to solve him，thx for help!!!!!!!!

Comment: This is probably a duplicate, and should be closed. Typically caused by trying to send messages after stopping the bus instance.